# A line of code is incomprehensible for me

Tags: java, android

> `newTilt = (newTilt > 90) ? 90 : newTilt;`

What does this line of code mean? It's the first time that I see something like this in Android.

This is the full method that contains the line above:

```
public void onTiltMore(View view) {
    if (!checkReady()) {
        return;
    }

    CameraPosition currentCameraPosition = mMap.getCameraPosition();
    float currentTilt = currentCameraPosition.tilt;
    float newTilt = currentTilt + 10;

    newTilt = (newTilt > 90) ? 90 : newTilt;

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder(currentCameraPosition)
            .tilt(newTilt).build();

    changeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```

Comment: Guess what, it's got its own Wikipedia page! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A

Comment: Man!! You need to revisit Java basic.. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a `ternary` expression. It says that if the newTilt at that point is above 90, it sets it to 90, otherwise it leaves it unchanged. You could *kind of* think of it in the way of an if-else statement.

```
 if(newTilt > 90) {
    newTilt = 90;
 } else {
    newtilt = newTilt; // which does nothing useful 
 }
```

Comment: Or `else { newTilt = newTilt; // does nothing`

Comment: @CompuChip indeed, but it's useless here so I left it out. Edited the answer because even though it is pointless, it is the more correct translation. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This expression means that

```
newTilt = (newTilt > 90) ? 90 : newTilt;
```

is an expression which returns one of two values, `90` or `newTilt`. The condition, `(newTilt > 90)`, is tested. If it is true the first value, 90 , is returned. If it is false, the second value, `newTilt`, is returned. Whichever value is returned is dependent on the conditional test, `(newTilt > 90)`

Answer (score 1):

It's as someone has already said, it's called a ternary expression. It's something that you should really learn as I've seen it appear on quite a few interview questions. What this expression does, is if the expression evaluates to true then the left-side of the colon is used as the result and if it evaluates to false, then the right side is used. It's very often used as a shortcut to an if/else statement. In fact, you could write the above like this:

```
if (newTilt > 90)
    newTilt = 90;
else
    newTilt = newTilt;
```

Obviously, you don't need the else statement above, as newTilt doesn't change if it's less than 90. I'm just trying to show you how the ternary works.

In fact, a ternary is still a conditional expression.

int var = (expression) ? true value : false value;

Since the false condition actually does nothing, the above ternary would be better written as simply:

```
if (newTilt > 90)
    newTilt = 90;
```

That's all you need.